# Finding mathematical expectation

Tags: probability

Suppose that a distribution of a random variable $X$ is given by,

$P(X=-1)=\frac{1}{6}=P(X=4)$ and

$P(X=0)=\frac{1}{3}=P(X=2)$.

Then, Find the value of $E\left(\frac{X}{X+2}\right)$.

(A) $\frac{1}{36}$

(B) $\frac{1}{18}$

(C) $\frac{1}{9}$

(D) $\frac{1}{6}$.

I am finding $E(X)=\frac{7}{6}$ and $E(X+2)=\frac{19}{6}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E(X)$ and $E(X+2)$ will not help. You want to find the value of $\frac{X}{X+2}$ in the cases $X=-1$, $X=4$, $X=0$, and $X=2$, multiply by the relevant probability, and add up.

It will not be difficult. For example, when $X=-1$, we have $\frac{X}{X+2}=-1$, so one term of your sum will be $(-1)(\frac{1}{6})$.

Comment: ok i got it! So answer is $\frac{1}{9}$.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose a discrete random variable $X$ have distribution $f_i=P(X=i)$,

then, $E(g(X))=\sum_ig(i)P(X=i)\tag{$g(X)$ is some function of $X$}$

Here $g(X)=\frac{X}{X+2}$

Answer (score 1):

You cannot find ${\rm E}\left[\frac{X}{X+2}\right]$ from ${\rm E}[X]$ and ${\rm E}[X+2]$. Instead use the [law of the unconscious statistician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) which states that
$$
{\rm E}[f(X)]=\sum_x f(x)P(X=x)
$$
for any nice function $f$. Use this with $f(x)=\frac{x}{x+2}$.